# When I will have

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, future-tense

I recently wrote a letter of motivation with this sentence

> Later on, when I will have more experience as a Salesperson, I plan on gaining responsibilities in...

Is this sentence correct ? Or should it be ***when I have more...*** ?

If the sentence is incorrect, how bad does it look from a native speaker's point of view ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Though I'm not a native speaker, I'm 99% sure that "When I have more experience" is the correct option. At least, I have encountered many cases of using present simple in describing future which were very similar to yours. For example:
When I get a new phone, I'll be very happy.
When you get home, I'll have already done my household chores

Comment: @JustLearn I agree with you and I'm not a native speaker either.

Comment: Lose the ***will***. Mostly we refer to the future in such contexts using Present Tense - *When I **grow** up*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Later on, when I will have more experience as a Salesperson

It's not necessary or usual to include "will".

---

**Note**

I'm giving an answer because others seem to be answering in the comments which is not in accordance with the SE rules. Giving an actual answer allows up-votes, down-votes and allows the OP to accept an answer if desired.

Comment: Ok thank you, I won’t make the mistake again. Can you tell me, as a native speaker, if you would notice this mistake, if you were to read it. I have a hard time assessing the level of incorrectness (I’ve already submitted my letter)

Comment: It is not you who did something wrong. It is the people who answered in comments. Yes, it is very noticeable as a native speaker. However we make allowances for people whose first language is not English. Do not worry too much about it (or, if you are worried about English, ask here of course!).  Note: If you think an answer is correct, you may use the tick mark to accept it. This will save others from coming to answer. However always wait for some time before accepting because a better answer may arrive!